# Graph API and iOS

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios, ios4

How can I use/implement the new Graph API from facebook in iOS programming (objective C)? Also parsing the JSON file returned by the API? I can't seem to find any examples out there. Facebook resources doesn't give too many details on iOS development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you downloaded the Facebook iOS SDK from here: http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk. It contains all you need to connect to Facebook from iOS and also sample code on how to use both the old API and the new Graph API.

Comment: I have downloaded the SDK from that link, but didn't see any sample code on how to parse and call the Graph API methods from objective-C

Comment: Take a look at the DemoApp project (located under sample). The DemoAppViewController.m files contains some sample code that should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score -1):

Just now i have tried to search the same thing here is the link what i have got.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph

hope its helpful.

Comment: You saved me a lot of my day.