# ios5 facebook app - do I really need git hub?

Tags: facebook, ios5, github

I've been reading about creating my first facebook app.  Some sites say I need git hub (but I'm having difficulties setting it up so would rather not do it), and some don't seem to say I need it.  I don't need to submit this to itunes, just test it on my device using facebook.

In this site:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/
Seems to say I need git hub.  I'm having trouble setting up my git hub.

However, this site:  http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/how-to-develop-facebook-application-for-iphone/
Seems to be starting with an example and doesn't require git hub, unless they missed that step.  Also, the example they refer to is DemoApp, but I'm not seeing how to find it.  I see hackbook, not DemoApp.  Does anyone else see DemoApp?  How do I find it...what clicks do I need to find it?

I have also seen on this site:  [Graph API and iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006382/graph-api-and-ios)
Refers to the Demo app.  Maybe it was re-named to hackbook?

I see another reference to that first link (instructions that say git hub is neded) here:
[Graph API and iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006382/graph-api-and-ios)
But I'm having trouble following the example.  I think it says something about dragging the facebook sdk into my project, but doesn't say how or where to drag from/to, plus I don't have git hub working.

So I guess that's 2 questions for now:
1. Do I need git hub to develop a facebook app for my ios device (ipod touch in my case).
2. Where is the Demo app referred to in the website?  I only see hackbook.

Thanks,
Mich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github is mentioned because the code of the Facebook sdk is loaded there and you need to get it from Github to your computer.

You can do that by cloning the repository as proposed in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#sdk), or you can simply download the code as a zip file from the project [page](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk).

As to the demo application, there is only hack book as you mentioned.

[image]

Comment: Someone was pointing out that the hackbook example is ios4 version instead of ios5.  I wonder what would be the best way to use it with ios5 code?  I'm not sure what the differences are, other than storyboard, but I've never written code for ios4.  Do you know what key differences are when porting code?

Comment: You probably should post this as a new question 1) so that it becomes more visible and you get better answers, 2) to be able to explain your question better and 3) because it is different from your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Question one: Github makes keeping control over your source code easy. If you have a Mac, you can download Github for Mac, which makes it even easier. Although it is not required for any project, you do need to download the SDK from Github.

Question two: The article you referenced with DemoApp was posted on August 20, 2010, the Facebook iOS SDK has has a lot of changes since then.